# How do I avoid duplicate Cartesian coordinates in my dynamically generated array? numpy.arange python 3.10

Tags: python, numpy, random, matrix-multiplication

I am working to generate a list of Cartesian coordinates in python3.10. The problem is, that of the 16 individual coordinates generated, the second 8 coordinate sets are identical to the first 8 coordinate sets. How do I ensure that all 16 coordinate sets are unique? My solution needs to scale up to 1,024 coordinate sets. I coupled numpy.arange() with a random number generator to get the desired array size. The duplication only seems to occur after I perform matrix multiplication to reduce the matrix from 4 dimensions to 3. Here is the code I currently have, and it's outputs:

```
import numpy as np

dims = 4         # User can enter a value between 4 and 10. 
magnitude = 1    # User can enter any number here.

verticesMatrix = 
    magnitude * 
    (2*((np.arange(2**dimensions)[:,None] & 
    (1 << np.arange(dimensions))) > 0) - 1)

rows = int(0)
cols = int(0)

projectionMatrix = np.ndarray(
shape=(dimensions-1, dimensions), ditype=np.int32)
    
for rows in range(dimensions-1):
    for cols in range(dimensions):
        if cols == rows:
            projectionMatrix[rows, cols] = 1
        else:
            projectionMatrix[rows, cols] = 0

myProjection = matrices.projectionMatrix(dims)
    myProjectionRows, myProjectionCols = np.shape(myProjection)
    myVerticesRows, myVerticesAxes = originalVertices[0].shape
    
    if myProjectionCols != myVerticesAxes:
        logging.error("# of Columns in Projection Matrix must be the 
                      same as the # of axes in each coordinate set 
                      from the Vertices Matrix.")
    else:
        myFlattenedHypercube = np.empty(
            (myVerticesRows, myProjectionRows))
        row = 0
        while row <= vertices - 1:
            myFlattenedHypercube[row] = np.matmul(
                myProjection, originalVertices[0][row])
            row += 1
```

The original matrix are the coordinates for the points that describe a tesseract, or hypercube. At the moment, this array, is fully four-dimensional (4D), as it has, effectively, x,y,z,w coordinates. In order to obtain a set of coordinates that can be graphed in three-dimensional space, we need to "flatten" the 4th dimension into the 3rd dimension, so we have only x,y,z coordinates.

Step 1: Generate coordinates for a tesseract.

Step 2: Generate a matrix that can "flatten" the tesseract into a three dimensional "projection".

Step 3: Multiply the projection matrix by the tesseract matrix, and the result is an array that has the same number of coordinate sets, but has only three dimensions in space.

```
My algorithm performs matrix multiplication, one row at a time. 

   A B C D        x  y  z  w   (A1*x1)+(B1*y1)+(C1*z1)+(D1*w1)=  x
1 [1,0,0,0] * 1 [-1,-1,-1,-1] = (1*-1)+ (0*-1)+ (0*-1)+ (0*-1)= -1
2 [0,1,0,0]                    (A2*x1)+(B2*y1)+(C2*z1)+(D2*w1)=  y
3 [0,0,1,0]                   = (0*-1)+ (1*-1)+ (0*-1)+ (0*-1)= -1 
                               (A3*x1)+(B3*y1)+(C3*z1)+(D3*w1)=  z
                              = (0*-1)+ (0*-1)+ (1*-1)+ (0*-1)= -1 
                      
such that the new row's coordinate set returns back as [-1, -1, -1], which you can see in row 1 of my "Returned Flattened Matrix". This is then repeated in the same manner for each additional row in the Original VerticesMatrix. The problem is, that in this example, every eight coordinate set that is flattened from 4D to 3D returns back a duplicate of the row    eight rows earlier.

('Original VerticesMatrix Generated:', array(
  [[-1, -1, -1, -1],
   [ 1, -1, -1, -1],
   [-1,  1, -1, -1],
   [ 1,  1, -1, -1],
   [-1, -1,  1, -1],
   [ 1, -1,  1, -1],
   [-1,  1,  1, -1],
   [ 1,  1,  1, -1],
   [-1, -1, -1,  1],
   [ 1, -1, -1,  1],
   [-1,  1, -1,  1],
   [ 1,  1, -1,  1],
   [-1, -1,  1,  1],
   [ 1, -1,  1,  1],
   [-1,  1,  1,  1],
   [ 1,  1,  1,  1]]))

('Projection Matrix:', array(
  [[1, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 1, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 1, 0]]))

("Returned flattened vertices:", array(
  [[-1., -1., -1.],
   [ 1., -1., -1.],
   [-1.,  1., -1.],
   [ 1.,  1., -1.],
   [-1., -1.,  1.],
   [ 1., -1.,  1.],
   [-1.,  1.,  1.],
   [ 1.,  1.,  1.],     # This is the 8th coordinate set
   [-1., -1., -1.],
   [ 1., -1., -1.],
   [-1.,  1., -1.],
   [ 1.,  1., -1.],
   [-1., -1.,  1.],
   [ 1., -1.,  1.],
   [-1.,  1.,  1.],
   [ 1.,  1.,  1.]]))   # This is the 16th coordinate set, and is identical to the 8th.
```

Am I just a poor fool subject to the laws of matrix multiplication yielding such an unfortunate result?

Comment: why use `ndarray`?  You use `np.empty! else where.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @hpaulj Good eye on 'np.empty'. I used np.arange() with the arguments I did, because it as actually generating the entire matrix of vertices in the single command. It outputs as the Original verticesMatrix.

I use np.empty() and set the size later on for the flattened vertices, because I will be setting the new value of each row in the array as a separate function, rather than all at once. The "flattening" has to be done per each coordinate set.

Comment: My Full code for this project is found at https://github.com/jGDarkness/dimensionality/blob/master/dimensionality_refactored.py

Answer (score 0):

My comment about `np.ndarray` had to do with this block of code:

```
In [4]: projectionMatrix = np.ndarray(
   ...: shape=(dimensions-1, dimensions), dtype=np.int32)
   ...: 
   ...: for rows in range(dimensions-1):
   ...:     for cols in range(dimensions):
   ...:         if cols == rows:
   ...:             projectionMatrix[rows, cols] = 1
   ...:         else:
   ...:             projectionMatrix[rows, cols] = 0
   ...: 
In [5]: projectionMatrix
Out[5]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

`ndarray` used this way is essentially the same as `empty`, creating an array with undefined values.  It's still fully populated.  I prefer to use `np.zeros` (unless using object dtype).  `ndarray` is low level array creator (read its docs).

But you don't need to iterate to create such an array.  Just use `eye`:

```
In [7]: np.eye(dimensions-1, dimensions, dtype=np.int32)
Out[7]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

I haven't tried to figure out what the rest of the code is doing.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that for me. One of my main goals with this project was to improve my overall python skills, and this well help me add one more tool! Glad to see there is another method to build my projections.